# Close iframe using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of iframes in my html page. Upon a button click, I would like to close the last iframe in the list. How do I do that?

Effectively, I want to do a window.close() on the last iframe and not a .remove().

Comment: you can't close an iFrame! you can only remove it...

Comment: display="none" ? style.height=style.width=0 ???

Comment: @mplungjan: I'm afraid that won't do. I'm currently removing the iframes but it causes problems, I believe, with NHibernate at a later stage in the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "close" an iframe? Like Sascha said, it's not something that can be closed. Do you just want to do something like change the source to "about:blank" to make it appear empty?

I have now made an example of this (http://jsfiddle.net/fZDk3/) that uses `$("#ifrm").attr("src", "about:blank");`

Comment: I want to close the "window" in the iframe. But your "about:blank" comment could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't quite change the source to "about:blank". Could you possibly elaborate on that?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant and how to do it.

Comment: I've just come across this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626300/how-to-close-an-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626300/how-to-close-an-iframe) while trying to find your question again. They are suggesting that you should be careful with about:blank if you are using https, and in that scenario, you should use a real blank html file.

Comment: yes I've seen that answer on SO before. I've also tried your code $("#ifrm").attr("src", "about:blank");. That doesn't work

Comment: Did you try my jsFiddle. That works for me in Firefox 5. What browser are you using? Can you post your code so I can see why it isn't working for you?

Comment: It is working on your site. But I think my question was worded wrongly.