# How to close a (javascript iframe) in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to close a (iframe) by a button click, but my code isn't working:

```
<td>
  <a href="utility.htm" toptions="group = links, shaded = 1, type = iframe, effect = fade, width = 900, height = 900, layout = quicklook">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_utility_serv" runat="server" width="244" height="71" 
                     onclick="btn_utility_serv_Click" />
  </a>
  <%-- <img src="images/demo_20.jpg" width="244" height="71" />--%>
</td>
```

When I click the btn_utility_serv, the iframe window will open. In that window there will be a button Close. I need to close this iframe window when I click Close button.

I wrote like this:

```
<a href="javascript: parent.window.close()">
  <img alt="" src="images/Close.png" style="border-color: #800000" />
</a>
```

Comment: An iFrame (inline-frame) is not a popup window, in fact it's almost the exact opposite...furthermore the code you have supplied is only a small portion of what would be relevant to the question.  Please format it correctly and provide a bigger picture of what your page(s) look like.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank.htm file on your site. Have the IFrame SRC set to the blank.htm, then remove the IFRAME.

Reference Question : [How to close an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626300/how-to-close-an-iframe)

Comment: Try this and let me know if it helps you.